# Firebase Realtime Database in React Application: How can I access the values?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks

I am developing an application with one moderator who writes in the database on click and guests only reading the data. You are the moderator if user===id is true. I want to call the click events for the guests that the moderator performs so that they see the results, too. But when I try to access the values, they say it is null. The only way is to click in the application as a guest what I don't want because the guests should be updated without doing anything. I am bit confused. So sorry in advance if my description is not very clear. Would be happy to have help.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(user && id){
        if(user===id){
            dbTimer.set(
                {lastUpdated: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000), isRunning});
        }
        else{
            dbTimer.child("IsRunning").on("value", snap=>setIsRunning(snap.val()));
            console.log("isRunning", isRunning) // null
            if(isRunning){
                mouseIsUpHandler();
            }
        }
    }
}, [user, id, isRunning, isDown]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mostly on the right track. I assume that `setIsRunning` is a `useState` update function. Calling this and immediately checking the value won't work because the `isRunning` variable has the original value prior to calling the update function. By checking the value inside the callback function you should be able to achieve your desired result.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(user && id){
    if(user===id){
      dbTimer.set(
        {lastUpdated: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000), isRunning});
    } else {
      dbTimer.child("IsRunning").on("value", 
        snap => {
          const newIsRunning = snap.val();
          setIsRunning(newIsRunning);
          console.log("isRunning", newIsRunning);
          if(newIsRunning){
            mouseIsUpHandler();
          }
        });
    }
  }
}, [user, id, isRunning, isDown]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes exactly, setIsRunning is a useState update function. The initial value for isRunning is false. I also already tried your solution before but it is still null unless I am not clicking as a guest somewhere to be quickly overwritten by null again.

Comment: I think you may need to update your dependency list to include `mouseIsUpHandler` and `setIsRunning` that way the effect will always use the latest version of those functions.